# How to handle writing to an OutputStream of BluetoothSocket in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-bluetooth

The [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#ManageAConnection) say that the `read(byte[])` and `write(byte[])` functions both are blocking calls so they should not be called directly from the main thread.

I understand that `read()` only returns when there is something to be read from the socket, but do I have to spawn a new thread every time I have to write a byte to the socket's output stream using `write()` as the docs say that this function too can block if the receiving side isn't reading from the socket fast enough.

Further, in the example of the docs, they have just called `write()` directly and even commented it saying that the function should be called directly from the activity.

So what is the right way to handle the situation when `write()` blocks, to prevent my app from freezing and eventually throwing an ANR? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In BLE, calls to BluetoothGatt's `readCharacteristic()` and `writeCharacteristic()` are not blocking. They return `true` if the operation was initiated successfully.

When the operation is complete, you will receive the results in your implementation of BluetoothGattCallback's `onCharacteristicRead()` and `onCharacteristicWrite()`

If you need to display some results on your UI, run these operation in the UI thread:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // UI operations ...
            }
        });
```

For more infos on `writeCharacteristic()`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#writeCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "write thread" that starts when your socket is created. Then use some form of message passing to send a message from your main thread containing the data to send. The "write thread" blocks while waiting for new messages. When it receives a message, it writes the data to the socket. Just remember to exit the thread when the socket closes.

With Android you can use Handler and Looper to create a worker thread that can handle messages. See for example https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a.

But if the receiver actually reads slower than you send, make sure you don't just post more and more messages faster than they are handled, or you'll eventually run out of memory.